# Scraping AJAX loaded content with python?

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, screen-scraping

So i have function that is called when i click a button , it goes as below

```
var min_news_id = "68feb985-1d08-4f5d-8855-cb35ae6c3e93-1";
function loadMoreNews(){
  $("#load-more-btn").hide();
  $("#load-more-gif").show();
  $.post("/en/ajax/more_news",{'category':'','news_offset':min_news_id},function(data){
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      min_news_id = data.min_news_id||min_news_id;
      $(".card-stack").append(data.html);
  })
  .fail(function(){alert("Error : unable to load more news");})
  .always(function(){$("#load-more-btn").show();$("#load-more-gif").hide();});
}
jQuery.scrollDepth();
```

Now i don't have much experience with javascript , but i assume its returning some json data from some sort of api at "en/ajax/more_news" .

Is there i way could directly call this api and get the json data from my python script. If Yes,how?

If not how do i scrape the content that is being generated?

Comment: Use `urllib2` to retrieve the data from the API, and `json.loads` to parse the JSON into a Python dictionary.

Comment: @Barmar What exactly do i need to send , are you suggesting something like this ?                                                                                                      `r = requests.post('http://inshorts.com/en/ajax/more_news', json={'category':'','news_offset':min_news_id})`

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much it. Then use `json.loads(r)` to parse the JSON response, and `r['html']` will contain the HTML from the response.

Comment: @Barmar I tried but it just redirected me to the home page .         `import json
import requests
min_news_id="68feb985-1d08-4f5d-8855-cb35ae6c3e93-1"
r = requests.post('http://inshorts.com/en/ajax/more_news', json={'category':'','news_offset':min_news_id})
print (r.url)`

Comment: Actually, it should probably be `data=`, not `json=`.

Comment: @Barmar I tried but it just returns the html of the home page instead of the json response .

Comment: Can you share the link?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham [Link](https://www.inshorts.com/en/read)   The show more button which executes the above script is at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to post the news id that you see inside the script to *https://www.inshorts.com/en/ajax/more_news*, this is an example using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

# pattern to extract min_news_id
patt = re.compile('var min_news_id\s+=\s+"(.*?)"')

with requests.Session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get("https://www.inshorts.com/en/read").content)
    new_id_scr = soup.find("script", text=re.compile("var\s+min_news_id"))
    print(new_id_scr.text)
    news_id = patt.search(new_id_scr.text).group()
    js = s.post("https://www.inshorts.com/en/ajax/more_news", data={"news_offset":news_id})
    print(js.json())
```

js gives you all the html, you just have to access the `js["html"]`.

Comment: It is giving empty result
O/P: `{'html': '\n\n'}`

Comment: You need to change the code like thi
`news_id = news_id.split('"')
   js = s.post("https://www.inshorts.com/en/ajax/more_news", data={"news_offset":news_id[1]})`

in your code `news_id` is showing **var min_news_id = "vxy8k83f-1"**
so I just extract news id value from it.
Now it is working properly

Comment: @SalmanMohammad, just use `patt.search(new_id_scr.text).group(1)`

Comment: Yes `patt.search(new_id_scr.text).group(1)` works.
it gives plain news id like `vxy8k83f-1`.

Comment: How long it will get the data from load more result?
like will it get the result from only one page that come after cliking on **load more button** or it will iterativley get result from load more option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script that will automatically loop through all the pages in **inshort.com**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from newspaper import Article
import requests
import sys
import re
import json

patt = re.compile('var min_news_id\s+=\s+"(.*?)"')
i = 0
while(1):
    with requests.Session() as s:
        if(i==0):soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get("https://www.inshorts.com/en/read").content,"lxml")
  new_id_scr = soup.find("script", text=re.compile("var\s+min_news_id"))
   news_id = patt.search(new_id_scr.text).group(1)

    js = s.post("https://www.inshorts.com/en/ajax/more_news", data={"news_offset":news_id})
    jsn = json.dumps(js.json())
    jsonToPython = json.loads(jsn)
    news_id = jsonToPython["min_news_id"]
    data = jsonToPython["html"]
    i += 1
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
    for tag in soup.find_all("div", {"class":"news-card"}):
        main_text = tag.find("div", {"itemprop":"articleBody"})
        summ_text = main_text.text
        summ_text = summ_text.replace("\n", " ")
        result = tag.find("a", {"class":"source"})
        art_url = result.get('href') 
        if 'www.youtube.com' in art_url:
            print("Nothing")
        else:
            art_url = art_url[:-1]
            #print("Hello", art_url)
            article = Article(art_url)
            article.download()
            if article.is_downloaded:
                article.parse()
                article_text = article.text
                article_text = article_text.replace("\n", " ")

                print(article_text+"\n")
                print(summ_text+"\n")
```

It gives both the summary from **inshort.com** and **complete news** from respective **news channel**.